# addEventListener not attaching to the right scope

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using the native DOM's `addEventListener` event like so:

```
const domElement = document.getElementById('ember464');
domElement.addEventListener('click', dosomething);
this._listeners.push({target: domElement, type: 'click', callback: dosomething});
```

this registered the event and stores it in a `_listeners` array so it can be cleaned up later. The good news is that this event does attach to the DOM but event though the target is clearly scoped to just the single button, the handler seems to fire whenever a click is detected *anywhere* on the document!

Am I doing something wrong?

p.s. here's the browser inspector looking at the `_listener` array ... note that highlighting the "target" does indeed point only to the button that I'm trying to target. AKA, the target is the DOM node, not the selector used to identify the node.

[image]

---

I've now looked at the debugger at the targeted DOM element and I see the following:

[image]

---

For anyone brave enough, here's a working demonstration of the code. The second button is triggered by the "click" event is the subject of this issue:

> https://ui-animate.firebaseapp.com/

The full source code is here: [link](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-animate/blob/5e80090d39a28796b1d6a086a4becc4d5ab7545b/addon/components/ui-animate.js#L74-L79)

Comment: Your code looks OK and I tested it (Chrome) and works as it should. Go to the debugger tools, inspect the ember464 element, select "Event listeners" and also select the checkbox for Ancestors, and see if it helps you.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex thanks for the suggestion; I've added a screen shot of the event listener that I've attached and it is attaching at the Window level even though i'm 99% sure I've captured the right scope for it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was in a bit of code I hadn't illustrated in the question. Modern browsers all support the DOM method `addEventListener` but in order to support older browsers who only have `attachEvent` I had added the following abstraction:

```
registerListener(target, type, callback) {
  const addListener = target.addEventListener || target.attachEvent;
  const eventName = target.addEventListener ? type : 'on' + type;

  addListener(eventName, callback);
},
```

The problem with this is that the "this" context is lost in the call. So instead I changed to the following:

```
registerListener(target, type, callback) {
  const listenerFunction = target.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent';
  const eventName = target.addEventListener ? type : 'on' + type;

  target[listenerFunction](eventName, callback);
},
```

Comment: You could have used addListener.apply(target,[eventName,callback]). I was about to suggest that the ui-animate function takes a domElement on which to work, but the one that is actually the source of the event is not specified and maybe it was because the shake ui-animate was defined outside the button and inside the window. Glad you solved it.